# Why am I expecting a status code of 200 but got a status code of 404 while unit testing in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, python-unittest

I am writing a unit test case in python using unittest and pytest for a file. Out of the many functions I am unable to understand why doesn't it execute as a successfully passed test case.
Here is function which displays a settings page,and upon a successfull call it displays an html page.

```
@app.route('/settings', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def settings():
    global application_inst
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Setting changed")

    return render_template('settings.html', user=session['user'], application=application_inst)
```

and the unit testcase for the function is written below as:

```
class MyApp(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app(db)
        self.client = self.app.test_client(self)

        with self.app.app_context():
            # create all tables
            db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_settings_passed(self):
        response = self.client.get('/settings', follow_redirects=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

The error that I get in the stacktrace is:

```
test_app.py::MyApp::test_settings_passed FAILED                          [100%]ENV :default
############ INIT ############
############ INIT ############
############ INIT ############

 
200 != 404

Expected :404
Actual   :200
<Click to see difference>
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: You are comparing the same status code twice and expect a different output the second time? Also `with pytest.raises(AssertionError)` doesn't make sense at that point, maybe you wanted to do something else? As an aside - don't mix unittest and pytest - some of it may work, some will not. Stick to one of them instead.

Comment: Even if I check the same status code once I get the same error. I wanted to see whether my call to /settings gets me a status code of 200 or not. @MrBeanBremen

Comment: Ah ok, you have the expected and actual arguments inverted in `assertEqual`, I didn't notice that. So you are expecting 200, but get 404 instead.

Comment: you are right! why is it happening the way its happening? @MrBeanBremen

Comment: @SimeonNedkov  RuntimeError: Application was not able to create a URL adapter for request independent URL generation. You might be able to fix this by setting the SERVER_NAME config variable.

Comment: Why are you expecting a 404 in the second check? That doesn't make sense. As @MrBeanBremen says: nothing's changed, why do you expect a different result? The second check should read `self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)` but it's not needed because you've already checked that in the first assert.

Comment: @SimeonNedkov yeah I've edited it. now my point is if I expect the function to give a status code of 200 why does it give an assertion error and say 200!=404?.

Comment: I don't think it will now... did you run the test again after removing the second assertion?

Comment: @SimeonNedkov Yes i removed it. It still gives the same error.

Comment: For some reason it looks like you are __expecting__ `404` error and not `200`, can you check again on your machine code that you have __expecting__ `200` and not `404`? It looks that you have more then this `self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)` test by the looks of a result... as this test expects 200 and not 404

Comment: Can you try removing `@login_required` for a moment? You are trying to access a protected endpoint without loging in (as far as I can tell). It should give you a 401 instead of a 404 but you never know how stuff behaves in testing/debug.

Comment: @simkus I have the expected and actual arguments inverted in assertEqual,So I am expecting 200, but get 404 instead.

Comment: ahh, got it. Ok, then, you could try to do the test not using `self.client` but using `requests` library with which you can call the same endpoint but with a full path (just to test it), if with the `requests` lib it will work, then you know that the way you set up `self.client` is incorrect and it needs altering.

Comment: @simkus the problem with requests is tho it runs(while I am running the app) the moment I stop the app from running the test fails and says of a ConnectionError. So maybe what you are saying about self.client holds true.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't create test client during unit test of Flask app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28027583/cant-create-test-client-during-unit-test-of-flask-app)

Comment: @simkus that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change so that `self.client` would be executed within `app_context()` as e.g.

```py
class MyApp(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app(db)
        self.client = self.app.test_client(self)

        with self.app.app_context():
            # create all tables
            db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_settings_passed(self):
        with self.app.app_context():
            response = self.client.get('/settings', follow_redirects=True)
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

I have created the same scenario and it works with and without `app_context` for me. Also I have used this command to execute tests:

```py
python -m unittest tests/test_the_test.py
```

---

Also it depends of how you have set up the app.
Used `python3.7` for example bellow.

Mine is like this:

```
├── app.py
├── index
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── routes.py
└── tests
    └── test_the_test.py
```

my `app.py` is like this:

```py
from flask import Flask



def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    from index import bp
    app.register_blueprint(bp)
    return app
```

My `index/__init__.py` like this:

```py
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint(__name__, '/')

from index import routes
```

my `index/routes.py` like this:

```py
from index import bp
from flask import jsonify

@bp.route('/test')
def test():
    print('goes here?')
    return jsonify({'result': True})
```

my `tests/test_the_test.py` like this:

```py
import unittest

from app import create_app


class MyApp(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app()
        self.client = self.app.test_client(self)

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_settings_passed(self):
        response = self.client.get('/test', follow_redirects=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_settings_failed(self):
        response = self.client.get('/test_not_exist', follow_redirects=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)
```

Executing this command:

```py
python -m unittest tests/test_the_test.py
```

And my setup works properly, does the testing and give a correct result for both when the endpoint exists and when it doesn't exist.

result:

```
python -m unittest tests/test_the_test.py 
.goes here?
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.006s

OK
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts for to solve the problem,though our way of project structure and the code is same(except the python version(mine is 3.6)) still my problem persists. Nevertheless I will accept your answer.

Comment: Basically 404 error means that the page was not found, are you sure that `'/settings'` is a correct endpoint? Because if the `self.client` could not access the app, you would get a different message. Maybe the endpoint `'/settings'` is called incorrectly, maybe it starts differently, e.g. `'/some/structure/settings'`?

Comment: @curious_guy also, have you tried my example? just setup and see if it works, then it means that it might be due to how your app is set up and maybe it's the `endpoint` problem mentioned above?

Comment: yes @simkus I have tried yours, it is working fine. I will have to look for how my app is set up,your answer has indeed been like a silver lining for me,Thanks alot!